# Create PDA for Language

Tags: formal-languages, automata, pushdown-automata

I am given the Language:

$L = ${$a^{n+k}b^{m+k}a^kb^n | m,n,k >0$}$ $

I am asked to design a push-down automaton for this language. I am new to this concept and i do not know how to approach it. I tried designing it in JFLAP as following:

[image]

and when i tried to test it it wouldn't work but it looks right to me. Please give me your opinion on this. Does it look right or does or look wrong?Please don't down-vote this question, just give me some steps I should follow for such type of problems. Are there any certain steps I should follow or something?

Comment: What is a push down automata?

Comment: I don't believe that language is context-free.

Comment: @Berci here is a link to explanation of push-down automata:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ejIAmp_Atw